# How to return a valid pointer in a factory method to derived class based on underlying OS

Tags: c++, c++11

I am unable to call private methods of derived class using pointer to base class returned by Factory method.

I would like to return a `unique_ptr` to Cat when user is running on WIN and `unique_ptr` to Dog when user is running on Linux.

**Base.h** pure virtual class

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void echo() = 0;
};
```

**Cat.h** - derived class of **Base**

```
#include "Base.h"

class Cat : public Base
{
public:
    void echo();
    void CatPrivateFunction();
};
```

**Cat.cpp**

```
#include "Cat.h"

void Cat::echo()
{
    std::cout << "In echo()" << std::endl;
}

void Cat::CatPrivateFunction()
{
    std::cout << "In CatPrivateFunction()" << std::endl;
}
```

---

**Dog.h** - derived class of Base

```
#include "Base.h"

class Dog
{
    void echo();
    void DogPrivateFunction();
};
```

**Dog.cpp**

```
#include "Dog.h"

void Dog::echo()
{
    std::cout << "In echo()" << std::endl;
}

void Dog::DogPrivateFunction()
{
    std::cout << "In DogPrivateFunction()" << std::endl;
}
```

---

**BaseFactory.h**

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include "Cat.h"
#elif __linux__
#include "Dog.h"
#endif
#include <memory>

class BaseFactory
{
public:
    static std::unique_ptr<Base> createBase();
};
```

**BaseFactory.cpp**

```
#include "BaseFactory.h"

std::unique_ptr<Base> BaseFactory::createBase()
{
#ifdef __linux__
        return std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Dog{});
#elif _WIN32
        return std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Cat{});;
#endif
}
```

---

In the following script

```
#include "BaseFactory.h"
int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base> p = BaseFactory::createBase();
    p->echo();
    p->CatPrivateFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

I'd expect the following output

> In echo()
>   In CatPrivateFunction()

But `p->CatPrivateFunction()` is failing as Base.h doesn't have `CatPrivateFunction()` member function.

How can this be done?

Comment: IIRC you need to use a dynamic_cast and check if the `unique_ptr<Base>` can be converted to `unique_ptr<Cat>`

Comment: @FMashiro you don't want to convert `unique_ptr<Base>` to `unique_ptr<Cat>`. Just to convert `Base` to `Cat`. There is a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read about [*upcasting* and *downcasting*](https://www.tutorialcup.com/cplusplus/upcasting-downcasting.htm).

What you need here is to *downcast* the "pointer to `Base`" to a "pointer to `Cat`".

Considering that you don't know the exact type that the pointer is pointing to, you need to use [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) and check that the result is not a null pointer:

```
if (auto cat = dynamic_cast<Cat*>(p.get()))
    cat->CatPrivateFunction();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't call `CatPrivateFunction()` without a valid pointer/reference to a  `Cat` object. Since you only have a pointer to a `Base`, you would have to use `dynamic_cast` to test if that `Base` pointer is pointing at a `Cat` or not, and if so then you can call `CatPrivateFunction()` on it, eg:

```cpp
#include "BaseFactory.h"
#include "Cat.h"

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Base> p = BaseFactory::createBase();
    p->echo();
    Cat *c = dynamic_cast<Cat*>(p.get());
    if (c)
        c->CatPrivateFunction();
    return 0;
}
```